# Rename TableRow Attribute Names

Tags: java, json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I've read in JSON from a source REST endpoint and am writing out to BigQuery table. I want to make the BigQuery table attributes more readable ie. From src_lat to source_latitude etc...

I have managed to create a TableSchema definition which fits purpose, my question is how do I map the TableRow definition from the source to the new target attributes?

Comment: the columns could be either remapped while parsing the JSON already or with https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/RowMutations.html

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I'm pretty new to this and haven't coded Java for about 15 years! This challenge is I'm not parsing the JSON myself I'm using a prebuilt method to do it.  `return Transport.getJsonFactory().fromString(input.replace("'", "\""), TableRow.class);` so I was hoping it could be done with the resultant <TableRows>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see `JsonFactory.parse()` in combination with https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/json/CustomizeJsonParser ...this permits customizing the parser, in order to parse into a destination class of objects, which has different field names. you'll have to `extend CustomizeJsonParser` and implement the method `handleUnrecognizedKey`, which is being called for all the field keys, which cannot be mapped directly and then re-map those fields properly, eg. in a `switch` statement.

one can also use the Jackson Streaming API to re-map the fields, see this [example](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api).